# Computing the cube under a different modulus

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Given a natural number $n$, we want to find another natural number $m$ coprime to $n$, such that on input $y=x^3 \pmod n$ for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}_n^* \cap \mathbb{Z}_m^*$, we must be able to compute $x^3 \pmod m$.

Note that it might be computationally infeasible to first compute the cubic root of $y$ modulo $n$. Therefore, the algorithm should cleverly pick $m$ in such a way it can later compute $x^3 \pmod m$.

Comment: PS: In the real-world problem I'm facing, there are several other restrictions on $m$ and $n$. However, I stated the question in a more general (and possibly a bit vague) setting, in favor of simplicity.

Comment: If $x \in \Bbb Z_n^*$, $x^3 \pmod m$ doesn't make sense. I have no idea what you want to do. Is it about computing $y \pmod m$ (which still doesn't make sense) ? Also, pick $m=1$.

Comment: @merico: I made a small change to correct that. $m=1$ is a valid but trivial choice. I'm more interested in non-trivial choices; say when $m$ and $n$ are of the same length.

Answer (score 2):

This question is difficult or impossible to answer, because every element of $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ has infinitely many representatives, many of which are different mod $m$.

For instance, say that mod 5 we have $y=2^3=8=3$ (mod 5), so $x=2$. Now, note that 7 is coprime with 5. Also notice that $3,8,13$ are all representatives of 3 (mod 5). But 3 (mod 7) is 3, 8 (mod 7) is 1, and 13 (mod 7) is 6. So $x^3$ isn't even defined mod 7.

You can't fix this by choosing another number to mod by, because if two numbers are coprime, then you always get different answers like this.

But if you're working with computer programs or something like that, it's possible that you only consider the case where you take the smallest positive representative; in that case, it may be possible to say something, but it depends on the origin of your problem.

Comment: 8 and 13 are not in $\mathbb{Z}_5^*$, so they are not valid choices for $x$. In your case, the only $x \in \mathbb{Z}_5^*$ that satisfies $x^3 \pmod 5 = 3$ is 2. Therefore, $x^3 \pmod 7 = 1$.

Comment: If those are the definitions you are working with, you can just choose $n$ to be prime and larger than $m$ or $m^3$, depending on whether you mod out before or after cubing.

Comment: @SadeqDousti It seems that what you call ${\mathbb Z}_n^*$ is not at all what everybody else calls ${\mathbb Z}_n^*$. It seems that when you say “${\mathbb Z}_n^*$”, you mean what everybody else calls $\lbrace k\in [1,n] | {\sf gcd}(k,n)=1 \rbrace$.